# Azure App Services High Memory Consumption Net Core

Tags: azure, memory-management, .net-core, out-of-memory

guys!
I'm new to managing server apps working under highload, and facing an issue. My application (.NET Core 2.1, using MVC controllers) is used as a simple REST service (clientes get and set data from Sql Server DB). Workload is around 100 requests per second (I use only one instance). The problem is that GC never (literally never) happens, memory usage climbs up to ~2 GB so every 30-60 minutes my app is being restarted. Most of the times restart happens silently, but sometimes one of following OOM exceptions is logged

```
Received an exception: [Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.], [   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddWithResize(T item)
   at System.PinnableBufferCache.AgePendingBuffers()
   at System.PinnableBufferCache.Restock(Object& returnBuffer)
   at System.PinnableBufferCache.Allocate()
   at System.Threading.Overlapped..ctor()
   at System.Threading.PreAllocatedOverlapped..ctor(IOCompletionCallback callback, Object state, Object pinData)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.InitializeInternals()
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs..ctor(Boolean flowExecutionContext)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs..ctor()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketSender..ctor(Socket socket, PipeScheduler scheduler)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection..ctor(Socket socket, MemoryPool`1 memoryPool, PipeScheduler scheduler, ISocketsTrace trace)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.RunAcceptLoopAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.UnbindAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at WillHeroServer.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\MyApp\src\MyApp\Program.cs:line 17], System.Private.CoreLib
```

```
Received an exception: [Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.], [   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.GetOrCreateAcceptSocket(Socket acceptSocket, Boolean checkDisconnected, String propertyName, SafeCloseSocket& handle)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AcceptAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AcceptAsync(Socket acceptSocket)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketTaskExtensions.AcceptAsync(Socket socket)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.RunAcceptLoopAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.UnbindAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at WillHeroServer.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\MyApp\src\MyApp\Program.cs:line 17], System.Net.Sockets
```

I thought that I've made a memory leak which leads to this behaviour, but I didn't. I even made and deployed an empty app (no routes, no nothing), and memory consumption for processing those amount of requests and retutrning BadRequest still raised up memory to the previous level and reset an app (though, delay between resets was a bit longer). App service plan is set to B2 (2x cores, 3.5 GB RAM). I tried to upgrade to B3, but it didn't help the situtation, so I rolled back.

1) Why does an empty app never release memory in my case?

2) Can Kestrel handle these requests count?

3) Did I miss some settings within Azure or is it seems fine and I should just make several app instances?

Comment: Have you already played around with Kestrel limits configuration ?  - i.e. .UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
    options.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 100;
 ..............}

Comment: @Avanish, yes I did. Unfortunately no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have a memory leak.  That's the definition of a memory leak, when memory grows and the GC is unable to reclaim it.

It generally means that the objects you're loading into memory still have a reference and are still "rooted" (have a reference).  You need to ensure that you have disposed of all of your objects properly (IDisposable).

Also, it's feasible that whatever you're reading in off of the wire is larger than your available memory.  That's the less likely of the scenario.

Changing your GC behavior to be single-thread is not a viable solution to your problem, however.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
<PropertyGroup> 
   <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
</PropertyGroup>
```

?

[Reducing .NET Core Memory Usage](https://blog.discountasp.net/reducing-net-core-memory-usage/)

I had an issue and this one seemed to work. You can google for different GCs.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't help

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing this as it changes the Garbage Collector from being multi-threaded to single-threaded.  This will have pretty obvious negative performance impact on your GC and consequently your application.  Especially when it comes to Gen 2 GCs and any potential LOH fragmentation.

Read more at - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#workstation-and-server-garbage-collection